# OnSuccessListener not executed: User's Location in Android - Google Services API

Tags: java, android, mobile, location, google-play-services

new to android here,

I have been following the guide at: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html to try and get the user's location. I have handled the logic for requesting location permissions from the user and provided the necessary permissions in the manifest file.

When I try to extract the longitude and latitude from my Location object, it is null. Below is a snippet from the class handling the location logic. The activity used for the location client is a member of the class.

```
public void getLocation() {
    locClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);

    } else {
        locClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(activity,
                new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            LocationRetrieve.location = location;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

The code sets up a client, and checks for permissions. If the permissions are fine, then the success handler should assign the resulting Location object to a static member of the class. This can then be used elsewhere.

However, from debugging and printing it seems that the onSuccess function never gets called and so the Location object is never set.

What am I doing wrong?